# Rails form_for check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a basic survey app. On my take survey page I'm looping through and displaying each answer option as a radio button or checkbox as a form_for to create a user's choice. The choices are working great for the questions that are single choice (or radio buttons), but they aren't saving for multi select questions. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the form I have for the checkbox.

It seems like I should do

```
<%= f.check_box :answer_id, answer.id %> <%= answer.title %> <br>
```

similar to how I'm creating the radio button but that throws an error

```
undefined method `merge' for 14:Fixnum
```

Here's my code that displays:

```
<h3>Questions:</h3>
<ul><% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
    <li><p><%= question.title %></p></li>
    <% choice = question.choices.build %>
    <% if question.single_response == true %>
    <%= form_for [question, choice] do |f| %>

            <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
            <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %> <%= answer.title %><br>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :survey_id, value: @survey.id %>
            <%= f.submit %>
            <% end %>

            <br />
            <% else %>
                <%= form_for [question, choice] do |f| %>
                    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
                    <%= f.check_box :answer_id %> <%= answer.title %> <br>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :survey_id, value: @survey.id %>
                    <% end %>
                    <%= f.submit %>
            <% end %>
            <br />
        <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Any idea what I need to do to get it to save the answer_id to the choice so that it actually creates the choice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checkboxes, you actually want to return an array as the parameter. There is a little funny syntax to this because we don't actually want to use the form builder methods. It should look something like this (adapt to your specific model names and methods)

```
<%= check_box_tag 'choice[answer_ids][]', answer.id %>
```

Using this syntax should tell Rails to compile all of the checked checkbox values into an array.

[This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast) goes over the topic.

Comment: That seems to be throwing an error - undefined method `answer_id[]'

Comment: I updated my answer above. You probably need to tweak it to use your own model names and methods and perhaps have to add an `answer_ids` method to the model representing the user's choice, but hopefully this gives you the general gist. Definitely watch the Railscast for a more detailed walkthrough.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I  always wondered what the _tag does :). I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

This question is a few years old but I think it deserves a better answer. Since you are using form_for (a model backed form), then you probably want to use the form_for `check_box` method that you originally tried to use. In your case, it would look like this:

`<%= f.check_box :choice, { :multiple => true }, answer.id, false %>`

[Here is the doc on this.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)